# copy table data from file to postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have exported my local database table to a file and wish to load it to my cloud db.
when using the command: `\copy <table name> from '<path>/<file name>.txt' delimiter ',' csv;` the data is copied without enforcing the unique rules that exist on the table as well as insert the ID column "as is", not following the serial numbering.

I know the command `update <table name> set <id column name> = DEFAULT;`

here is the tricky part: I'm exporting other tables as well that have references to eachother

is there a way to achieve these two goals?

Comment: The premises are false: `copy` actually enforces unique constraints, and serial auto-numbering happens by default, just like with INSERT. If that doesn't work for you, please show a reproducible example or expand on the specifics of your case.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is relatively tricky.  You need to load the tables in the correct order.  Otherwise you will have foreign key problems.  I think the best way to do this is manually, but you could look at `pg_depend` and `pg_constraint` to see what you need to find to automate the order.